# how to find the index of its previous appearance on python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

(i just edited the question with multiple line of inputs)
For each word from this text find the index of its previous appearance in the text. The index of the first word is 0. If a word occurs the first time print -1.

for example:
input is: (4 line of inputs)

```
She sells sea shells on the sea shore;
The shells that she sells are sea shells I'm sure.
So if she sells sea shells on the sea shore,
I'm sure that the shells are sea shore shells.
```

output is :

> -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 2 -1 -1 3 -1 -1 1 -1 6 9 -1 -1 -1 -1 11 12 14 15 4 5 22 -1 16 -1 10 25 23 13 26 -1 -1

She [0] sells [1] sea [2] shells [3] on [4] the [5] sea [6] shore [7] ...

For sea in 6th position previous appearance was in position 2.

I try to use the get method, but now sure how to get index value through `get()`

my code :(i need take those strings from input)

```
while True:
   ans = input().split()

   if len(ans)==0:
       break
   else:
       lst = [-1 if i == ans.index(ans[i]) else i-ans[:i][::-1].index(ans[i])-1 for i in range(len(ans))]
       print(*lst)
```

Comment: `s = 'She sells sea on on the sea shore sea'`. What is the expected output here?

Comment: i think it should be -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 2 -1 6

Comment: Shouldn't it be -1 -1 -1 -1 3 -1 2 -1 6 ?

Comment: your right, should be -1 -1 -1 -1 3 -1 2 -1 6

Comment: `print(lst)` should do the job. Any specific reason why `print(*lst)` is used?

Comment: @susenj add * to avoid square brackets for output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to iterate the words:

```
s = 'She sells sea shells on the sea shore by shells sea'.split()
lst = [-1 if i == s.index(s[i]) else i-s[:i][::-1].index(s[i])-1 for i in range(len(s))]

print(lst)
```

Output

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, 6]
```

--- Update ---

`split()` also works for multi-line strings, so the same code can be used:

```
s = '''
She sells sea shells on the sea shore;
The shells that she sells are sea shells I'm sure.
So if she sells sea shells on the sea shore,
I'm sure that the shells are sea shore shells.
'''

print(repr(s))  # confirm newline characters

s = s.split()

lst = [-1 if i == s.index(s[i]) else i-s[:i][::-1].index(s[i])-1 for i in range(len(s))]

print(lst)
```

Output

```
"\nShe sells sea shells on the sea shore;\nThe shells that she sells are sea shells I'm sure.\nSo if she sells sea shells on the sea shore,\nI'm sure that the shells are sea shore shells.\n"
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 1, -1, 6, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, 11, 12, 14, 15, 4, 5, 22, -1, 16, -1, 10, 25, 23, 13, 26, -1, -1]
```

--- Update #2 ---

If you want the user to enter each line separately, you can use a list to gather the full text.

```
txt = []

i = '-'
while i:
   i = input('Enter line or return to end: ')
   txt.append(i)
   
s = ' '.join(txt).split()

lst = [-1 if i == s.index(s[i]) else i-s[:i][::-1].index(s[i])-1 for i in range(len(s))]

print(lst)
```

Output

```
Enter line or return to end: She sells sea shells on the sea shore;
Enter line or return to end: The shells that she sells are sea shells I'm sure.
Enter line or return to end: So if she sells sea shells on the sea shore,
Enter line or return to end: I'm sure that the shells are sea shore shells.
Enter line or return to end:
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 1, -1, 6, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, 11, 12, 14, 15, 4, 5, 22, -1, 16, -1, 10, 25, 23, 13, 26, -1, -1]
```

--- Update #3 ---

This generates the result using the defaultdict object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = '''
She sells sea shells on the sea shore by shells sea
'''
words = s.split()

idx = [(w,i) for i,w in enumerate(words)]  # word, index

d = defaultdict(list) # each element is empty list

for k, v in idx:
    d[k].append(v)  # get word indexes

print(d)  # {'She': [0], 'sells': [1], 'sea': [2, 6, 10], 'shells': [3, 9], 'on': [4], 'the': [5], 'shore': [7], 'by': [8]})

lst = [-1] * len(words)  # default -1

for k,v in d.items():
   if len(v) > 0:  # word appears more than once
      for i in range(1,len(v)):  # iterate indexes
          lst[v[i]] = v[i-1]

print(lst)  # [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, 6]
```

Comment: `s = 'She sells sea on on the sea shore sea'` . It may not give the previous appearance for the last word `sea` which is 6

Comment: @Mike67 Hi, can you take a look at my code(which copied your solution), let me know why it did not work. thanks

Comment: I edited your question to fix indents. It seems to work correctly. Do you want all the inputs merged to a single string?

Comment: @Mike67 since i need take the input line by line, if you try my code, input the first line then press enter, then input second line, .... input fourth line, press enter and press enter again to finish input, then the output is  `-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1`

Comment: the second edit works for my case, thank you. i think i have a long to go to learn python

Answer (score 0):

Just use a traditional `for` loop:

```
string = 'She sells sea shells on the sea shore'

lst = string.split(' ')

existing = []

for elem in lst:
    if existing.count(elem) == 0:
        print(f"{elem} = -1")
    else:
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == elem]
        index = indices[existing.count(elem) - 1]
        print(f"{elem} = {index}")
    existing.append(elem)
```

Output:

```
She = -1
sells = -1
sea = -1
shells = -1
on = -1
the = -1
sea = 2
shore = -1
```

Comment: We need previous appearance, not the first appearance of the word.

Comment: What do u mean by that?

Comment: `s = 'She sells sea on on the sea shore sea'` . For the last word `sea`, it should give 6 instead of 2

Comment: Why should it give 6? It should only give 3 as the word `sea` only occurs 3 times in the string.

Comment: OP needs the "index" of the "previous appearance" of the word. Not the "count" of it.

Comment: @susenj Thanks for ur suggestion. I have edited my answer. Pls check it out

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it (example in IPython):

```
In [1]: txt = "She sells sea shells on the sea shore"
Out[1]: 'She sells sea shells on the sea shore'

In [2]: words = txt.split()
Out[2]: ['She', 'sells', 'sea', 'shells', 'on', 'the', 'sea', 'shore']

In [3]: seen = {}
Out[3]: {}

In [4]: indexes = []
Out[4]: []

In [5]: for w in words:
   ...:     if w not in seen:
   ...:         seen[w] = 0
   ...:         indexes.append(-1)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         seen[w] += 1
   ...:         indexes.append(seen[w] + 1)
   ...:         

In [6]: indexes
Out[6]: [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1]
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem for all testcases.

Comment: That's because they weren't there yet when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'She sells sea shells on the sea shore sea shells'
l = list(s.split())
res = []
curr_latest={}
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] in curr_latest:
        res.append(curr_latest[l[i]])
    else:
        res.append(-1)
    curr_latest[l[i]]=i
print(res)
print(curr_latest)
```

You can use index method of list to get first occurrence of element

Comment: Won't work for the input `s = 'She sells sea on on the sea shore sea'` . OP needs preiovus appearance index, not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need of **while** loop.
Secondly, the statement **ans = list( input().split())** there is no need of writing list(.. ..).  The **split()** returns in list format only.

now here's my solution:

```
lis = []
t_lis = []
ans = input().split()
print(ans)
if len(ans) == 0:
    print("RECEIEVD NO TEXT")
else:
    for word in ans:
        if word not in t_lis:
            lis.append(-1)
            t_lis.append(word)
        else:
            lis.append(ans.index(word))
print(lis)
```

I had tried not to  change your logic format.
Hope this helped you and and you learned something new today.

Comment: Please look at the question carefully. This doesn't address all the test scenarios.